# How to pass a parameter from docker-compose to service runned in docker image?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml`, among other images, uses [official mongo docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/3.2/Dockerfile):

```
mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:3.2
    volumes:
        - mongo_data:/data/db
    ports:
        - "57017:27017"
    restart: always
```

The problem is that I need mongo deamon to run with `--httpinterface` option. How can I change my `docker-compose.yml` to pass this parameter to the final `CMD ["mongod"]`?

Is it possible without touching the mongo image? Forking this image to only add one parameter would be an overkill.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `command` option of `docker-compose.yml`

```
mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:3.2
    command: mongod --httpinterface
    volumes:
        - mongo_data:/data/db
    ports:
        - "57017:27017"
    restart: always
```

Comment: Note that MongoDB 3.6 removes the deprecated HTTP interface. You can see from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#http-interface-and-rest-api)